# Codeigniter create a simple form to update the db

Tags: codeigniter

ugh, im still having problems understanding forms. Ive watched a few guides/videos with no luck (keep in mind im running withough much sleep) so I thought i could ask for help here.

suppose i have a table called Notes and inside the Notes table i have a column called "user" and "note"

I simply want to edit that "note" and "user" in the Notes table using a form and submit button.

could someone put together what the controller and model should look like for this? I know im asking alot so i appreciate your time.

**edit1**

My model:

```
function edit($id)
{
          $this->db->where('id', $id);
          $this->db->update('company_contacts', $data);

}
```

controller:

```
public function edit($id) { 
            if (isset($_POST["edit"]))
            {
                $this->Notes_model->edit($id);
                $url = "/notes/view/" . $id;
                redirect($url);
            }
        $data['data']  = $this->Notes_model->view($id);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('notes/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
   }
```

Comment: what have your tried?

Comment: i just edited the question to add my current model and controller. However ive modified it 100 times so its not correct atm.

Comment: Your posted code should throw errors / notices in the model's edit() function as-is, since you use $data but that variable is undefined in the function. What is $data supposed to be in that function ?

Comment: i want $data to be $_POST['note'] and $_POST['user']

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it. The approach is a little different from what you have done as I use helpers. For using my code, you need to have `input` helper enabled.

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id) { 
  if (isset($this->input->post('edit'))
  {
    $this->load->model('Notes_model'); // You might have missed out on loading the model

    // Since you wish to edit the note and user fields in your table, you need to get the value from the page you are submitting the request from
    $note = $this->input->post('note');
    $user = $this->input->post('user');

    $data = array(
      'note' => $note,
      'user' => $user
    );

    $this->Notes_model->edit($id, $data);
    $url = "/notes/view/" . $id;
    redirect($url);
  }
  $data['data']  = $this->Notes_model->view($id);
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('notes/edit', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Model**

```
function edit($id, $data)
{
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $this->db->update('company_contacts', $data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Your model should be

```
function edit($id)
{
    $data = array(
               'note' => $_POST['note'],
               'user'=> $_POST['user']// I don't think you need this. 
            );

     $this->db->where('id', $id);
     $this->db->update('company_contacts', $data);

}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would directly pass input values to a model instead of taking them through a controller.